Asynchronous Behaviour for useParams hook
How do we manage the behaviour of useParams
How it triggers in before or after useEffect
import react,{useEffect} from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

export default Slip(){
  const {slug} = useParams()
  useEffect(() => {
    // In my application role of slug is very important for application behaviour 
    const fetchdata = async () => {
      const getd = await axios.post('backend.com',{slug})
      // Here slug needs to be loaded completely without it application can't behave properly 
    }
  },[])
}

My company is working on a banking project where we take slug from parameter which is very important to get loaded to delete the transaction
So is there any way for asynchronous Behaviour of useParams or **when parameters are loaded then only code will execute **

"So is there any way for asynchronous Behaviour of useParams or when parameters are loaded then only code will execute" - Huh!? useParams is completely synchronous... you either have a defined slug value based on the current route path, or you don't, but you will always know this immediately. What exactly is the issue or problem you have in your app code? Are you rendering this Slip component on a path where the slug segment is optional?

FWIW slug should absolutely be included in the useEffect hook's dependency array as per David's answer below, but what you describe as a "problem" just isn't possible.

If a non-empty value for slug is required before performing the logic in useEffect, check the value before performing that logic.  You can also add slug to the dependency array for the effect so it will re-run whenever the value changes.  For example:
  useEffect(() => {

    if (!slug) return; // <-- return early if no value is found

    // the rest of the effect...

  }, [slug]) // <-- re-run the effect if the value changes


I think you will have no problem
useParams is not the react hook, it's officially provided by react-router-dom
So technically,it will process the slug with your component and provide it before that route code is loaded
you can do simple validation on backend or frontend
if(!slug) return
